# Design incorrect when calling from specified view

Tags: ios, layout, xcode7

I have Home Screen and Side menu when calling view from side it looks right like the first image, when called it from home screen design break down like second image.
[image: When calling it from side menu]
[image: When calling from home screen]

Code of `prepareForSegue`:

```
if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"SellPropUpdateSegue"]) { 
    UITableViewCell *cell = sender; 
    // Get reference to the destination view controller
    SellPropertyUpdateViewController *sell = [segue destinationViewController]; 
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:cell]; 
    NSLog(@"%@",[_PropertyIDArray[indexPath.row]stringValue]); 
    sell.sellPropID=[_PropertyIDArray[indexPath.row]stringValue]; 
    //NSLog(@"%li",(long)rev.tag); 
}
```

Comment: Can you show us some code? How do you show the view? What are the constraints? Is "automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets" seated to yes on your ViewController?

Comment: if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"SellPropUpdateSegue"])
    {
        UITableViewCell *cell = sender;
        // Get reference to the destination view controller
        SellPropertyUpdateViewController *sell = [segue destinationViewController];
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:cell];
        NSLog(@"%@",[_PropertyIDArray[indexPath.row]stringValue]);
        sell.sellPropID=[_PropertyIDArray[indexPath.row]stringValue];
        //NSLog(@"%li",(long)rev.tag);     
    }

Comment: I edited your question with the code posted here, how is the table configured? Do you set the scrollviewInset manually?